# Systemd: Start service if a path is found but only between 9AM and 6PM

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I wonder if there's some way to have both the functionality of a Path unit and a Timer. The idea is to start a specific service if a path on the system is found but only between 9AM and 6PM.

Currently I've the following path / service that will start `ffmpeg` every time a USB camera is available at `/dev/video4`.

**camera.path**:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB Camera Stream Service Path

[Path]
PathExists=/dev/video4
Unit=camera.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**camera.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB Camera Stream Service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video4 -copyinkf -codec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/stream
```

Note: I also want to be able to run `systemctl start camera.service` to start the service manually anytime I would like to.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to have `systemd` execute a script that tests the current time and executes your command if it is in the range specified.

Create the script as, for example, `/usr/local/bin/myscript`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(date +%H) -ge 9 -a $(date +%H) -le 18 ]; then
    ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video4 -copyinkf -codec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/stream
fi
```

Be sure to give the script execute permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

Then change this line in `camera.service`:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video4 -copyinkf -codec copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/stream
```

To this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript
```

Comment: Well, that's an option. Thank you. :)